# jquery: determine if a string contains characters of an array

Tags: jquery, arrays, string

i'm having the following code:

```
var specialchars = [246,214,228,196,252,220,223]; // holds german umlauts + ß
var foo = "abcdefä41hl";
```

what's the best practise for detecting if foo contains a character's ascii-code from the array? in that case it would return true as it contains "ä" (ascii code 228).

thanks

Comment: JavaScript uses the UTF-16 encoding of Unicode, not ASCII. So ß, for example, is better written as "ß" or ["\u00df"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00df/index.htm). (ß isn't even an ASCII character.) So, why not make `specialchars` an array of strings?

Answer (score 1):

You can detect that by,

```
var specialchars = [246,214,228,196,252,220,223];
var foo = "abcdefä41hl";
var isExist = !!([...foo].find(itm => specialchars.includes(itm.charCodeAt())));

console.log(isExist); // true
```

Or you could use `Array.prototype.some` instead of `find` as suggested in the comment,

```
var isExist = [...foo].some(itm => specialchars.includes(itm.charCodeAt()));
```

Comment: You might want [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `find`, so that it returns a boolean.

Comment: @4castle Updated! Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: sorry to bother you but is [...foo] the correct syntax? it's not working .. :/ would you please update the solution?

Comment: @Fuxi Nothing is gonna bother me. :-) Are you using ES6? That one is called as spread operator.

Comment: @Fuxi If `[...foo]` isn't working, you can also do `foo.split('')` for that part.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easily:

```
foo.split("").filter(c => specialchars.indexOf(c.charCodeAt()) != -1).length != 0
```

It splits the string to an array of chars, keeps only the ones that exist in the list of special characters and checks if any are left.